# Reset Skype password not possible when email is microsoft account but not linked

Tags: skype, password-recovery

I forgot my Skype password and was trying to reset it with the form at https://login.skype.com/recovery but it redirects me to the account/password recovery of my microsoft account. (Probably because there exists a microsoft account with that email.) But those accounts are not linked. I know my microsoft account credentials, but can't use them to log in to skype. Is there any way to make skype send me a password recovery email to that email like they do for other emails?

Comment: Hey! Did you ever find a solution for this problem? My friend is having this exact same problem. We browsed the internet for a few hours straight and did not find a single working solution. :/